# How can I show that these 2 spans are the same?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $\vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2, \ldots,\vec{x}_k$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $\vec{y} = a_1\vec{x}_1 + a_2\vec{x}_2 + \cdots + a_k\vec{x}_k$ and $\vec {a}_i \ne 0$. How can I show that $\operatorname{span}(\vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2, \ldots, \vec{x}_k) = \operatorname{span}(\vec{y}, \vec{x}_2, \ldots, \vec{x}_k)$?

I'm not seeing how this intuitively makes sense. Can't I make the coefficient for $\vec{x}_1$ to be $0$ in the first span with only $\vec{x}$ and then the other $\vec{x}_i$ might not make all the same vectors which makes a different set? How do I go about doing proving it?

Comment: This amounts to showing $x_1\in$ the right hand side, which isn't difficult, and a little explanation.

Comment: @DavidP Wouldn't I have to prove that vectors in the right hand side are also elements of the left hand side? So that both are subsets of each other? Like if I make all coefficients for vectors on the left to be 0 and get $\vec{0}$, I wouldn't really be able to get $\vec{0}$ on the right if $\vec{a_1} \ne 0$ no?

Comment: $y$ is by definition, the $x_i's$ need coefficient 1, all others coefficient 0.

Comment: @DavidP Perhaps I'm just not understanding you but if $a_1 \ne 0$, how would I be able to get any vector on the right that needs to have $a_1 = 0$ which I can get on the left? Like I can get $0\vec{x}_1 + \vec{x}_2 + ... + \vec{x}_k$ on the left but how will I do that on the right with $a_1 \ne 0$? It just doesn't make any sense to me that they can be the same.

Comment: You can give $y$ a coefficient of zero if you like?

Comment: Ohhhhh ok I was just confusing myself since I was so wrapped up in $a_1 \ne 0$ and I totally forgot I can just give y a coefficient of 0. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can set containment in both directions in a relatively straightforward way.

If $y=a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2+ \ldots + a_k x_k$, with $a_i \neq 0$ for each $i$, then by definition $y\in \operatorname{span}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k)$. Clearly, for $i>1$ we have $x_i\in \operatorname{span}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k)$. So $\operatorname{span}(y, x_2, \ldots, x_k) \subseteq \operatorname{span}(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k)$.

Since, $y=a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2+ \ldots + a_k x_k$, with, in particular, $a_1 \neq 0$, it follows that $x_1=(1/a_1)(y - a_2/ x_2 - \ldots - a_k x_k)$. So $x_1\in\operatorname{span}(y, x_2, \ldots, x_k)$. Clearly, for $i>1$ we have $x_i\in \operatorname{span}(y, x_2, \ldots, x_k)$. So $\operatorname{span}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k) \subseteq \operatorname{span}(y, x_2, \dots, x_k)$ and the result follows.

As you pointed out in a comment above, this isn't true if $a_1=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I may have been assuming you know more than you do in the comments. Here is a breakdown, and you may need to prove number 1.

1. If $z\in \text{span}(S)$ then $\text{span}(S)=\text{span}(S\cup \{z\})$
2. $y\in \text{span}(\{x_1,...,x_k\})$ so $\text{span}(\{x_1,...,x_k\})=\text{span}(\{x_1,...,x_k,y\})$

*3. $x_1\in \text{span}(\{y,x_2,...,x_k\})$ so $\text{span}(\{y,x_2,...,x_k\})=\text{span}(\{x_1,...,x_k,y\})$

4. Use transitivity of set equality.

To show 3 above, solve for $x_1$ as a linear combination of $y, x_2,...,x_k$.